# Sistema de calificacion Php mysql

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli

Pues aquí con una duda:

Actualmente tengo un sistema de calificación de usuarios.

Mi pregunta es como ¿podría guardar el id de el usuario al que deseo calificar?, para que posteriormente al hacer un SELECT me traiga en consola todos los comentarios y la calificación que tiene ese usuario.

El código esta así:

```
<?php
session_start();
require'conexion.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
   header("Location: index.php");
}
?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?";   
$id = $_GET['id'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

if ($stmt) {

$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

$statement = mi_fetchassoc($stmt);

       }


function mi_fetchassoc($stmt)
{
if($stmt->num_rows>0)
{
    $rs = array();
    $md = $stmt->result_metadata();
    $params = array();
    while($field = $md->fetch_field()) {
        $params[] = &$rs[$field->name];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
    if($stmt->fetch())
        return $rs;
}

return null;
}

?>

<?php 
require "conexion.php";
if(isset($_POST)){
if(mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO comentarios (comentario, rating, usuario, fecha, id_us) VALUES ('".$_POST['comentario']."', '".$_POST['rating']."', '".$_SESSION['id_usuario']."', NOW(), '".$statement['id']."')")){
    echo "1";       
}else{
    echo "2";
}
}
?>
```

Donde:

Comentario: es la opinión del comprador.

Rating: es el valor del 1 al 5 en calificación.

Usuario: Aquí guardo el id del usuario de la sesión actual. **COMPRADOR**

Fecha: el now trae la fecha actual.

**id_us: Aquí quiero guardar el id del usuario al que estoy calificando y donde marca el error.** **VENDEDOR**

**TABLA comentarios:**

id primary key int(11) auto increment not null,

comentario varchar(100) not null,

rating int(11) not null,

usuario varchar(30) not null,

fecha datetime default null,

id_us int (11)

**TABLA usuarios:**

id int(11) primary key not null auto_increment,

usuario varchar(30) not null,

email varchar(30) not null,

pw varchar(30) not null,

nombre varchar(30) not null.

Espero alguien pueda resolverme esta duda.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola. Por lo pronto la query `"SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?"` no tiene ningún sentido, porque ¿obtienes la misma id que ya tienes? Esto podría servir en un momento dado para saber si la **id** existe en la BD, pero por tu código entiendo que la id la tienes de la sesión de usuario, conque ya la recuperaste al hacer login.

Comment: Hola @Orici la query sirve para sacar los datos del usuario al que estoy calificando, en este caso el ID, pero no se como guardar ese id en mi tabla comentarios, no se si me explico. Saludos.